# Is it possible to detect usb devices using php?

Tags: php, usb

Is it possible to detect usb mouse,keyboard or flash drives when they are connected using php?

Comment: On a web server? Or on a web client? Or when running php without any webservers involved?

Comment: In PHP alone, no. But php can reach out to the OS e.g. via [`system()`](http://de.php.net/system) - that could work in conjunction with other programs, which perform the actual detection.

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a matter of PHP, but of the underlying operating system. If the operating system detects it and makes the information readable for the user that runs the PHP script, you can "detect" devices using PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Which side - server side or client side?

Server side: possible, although probably not a good idea. You would call OS specific functions or shell commands to access USB (e.g. shell_exec("lsusb -v"); ), and process the results.

Client side: No. PHP just works on server side.

Commandline PHP: same as Server side.

*You are using the wrong tool for the job. Go back and use one more suited to the task.*

Comment: *Go back and **use** one more suited to the task.*?

Comment: This was downvoted because of the directive to use a different solution, criticizing the author's choice (or maybe there is no choice), and not providing a sample "right tool for the job.'