# How to detect if USB Stick is inserted into pc?

Tags: php, angular, usb, angular6, codeigniter-3

I want to prevent lunching software made with **angular 6** and **php** **codeigniter** if **USB** is not inserted into pc, if user start the software, the software should check if a usb is inserted, if true the software launches and if false, a message will pop up saying you need to insert the USB.

is there a way to detect if USB inserted using javascript or php?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: [PHP : Detecting USB device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122263/php-detecting-usb-device)

Comment: I would say no. At least not without talking to the OS using the shell.

Comment: You might implement server-side authentication via a [U2F/FIDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) key.